# meta tag content "&" gets converted to "&amp;"

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js

In my Nextjs webapp I'm using Firebase to store images and the uri contains "&" sign that gets converted to "&" inside Head component, for example if I create this simple tag `<meta property="test" content="&"/>` it ends up to look like `<meta property="test" content="&amp;"/>`, Unfortunately this causing Firebase to throw 403 Error.

Is there a way to stop Nextjs from replacing & sign?

"next": "12.3.4",

```js
import Head from 'next/head'

function Page({ ssrData }) {
  const { imageUrl } = ssrData
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <meta property="og:image" content={imageUrl} />
      </Head>
      <>
        ...
      </>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Please provide the full meta tag in your question along with the react code that is creating it. It may be that the approach used is what is causing it. Also, how is it causing Firebase to throw a 403? How is the value being used?

Comment: I just added a code snippet. When you upload an image to Firebase it creates url that can be stored in db and used later, it has parameters added for example "?alt=media&token=8240134r-a79j-63g6-2385-7c338a5ecd74", the problem is that next/head replaces the "&" sign with "&amp;" which breaks the url

Comment: Seems like a long standing issue with React (see [`facebook/react#13838`](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13838)). If your website is hosted by Firebase, you could maybe use a [URL redirect](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#redirects) to reconstruct the URL with the token, or you could upload the file itself into your hosting image.

Comment: interesting, thanks for the url, I'll try one more thing and try to put meta tag inside the body which should still be valid

Answer (score 0):

try this [react-html-attributes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-attributes)

```
import { htmlEscape } from 'react-html-attributes';

///.....

<Head>
  <meta property="test" content={htmlEscape('&')} />
</Head>
```

Comment: This will set the `innerHTML` of the tag, not the `content` attribute

Comment: pleas let me know , is it now ok ?